# How to Positioning div tags using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have had problems with positioning `div` tags using **CSS**.

What code would you use to make a `div` either **positioned in the top**, **top right**, **top left** etc.?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: You are looking for a tutorial or a guide to css: http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `position: absolute` and the `top`, `left`, `bottom`, and `right` CSS properties:

```css
.top { top: 0 }
.bottom { bottom: 0 }
.left { left: 0 }
.right { right: 0 }
.center { left: 0; right: 0; margin: 0 auto; }

div {
  position: absolute;
  width: 5em;
  height: 5em;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="top center"></div>
<div class="bottom center"></div>
<div class="top left"></div>
<div class="bottom left"></div>
<div class="top right"></div>
<div class="bottom right"></div>
```